# Change Navigation Menu Icon & Header Data in Salesforce1 App

Tags: salesforce1-app, header-bar

I am new to salesforce1 & I am trying to change the Header of Application.

I want to put some other button or link in header of the Salesforce1 Application.

Here is my screenshot :

[image]

I want to change the `Navigation icon` & in `right side there is a bell sign, i want to put send/ cancel button(or link) there`.

I have see some tutorials but I don't get the exact thing so is there any way to `change the Header` details.

I know how to change color of it, it's from `Mobile Administration`.

So Help me on it.

Should I have to create custom Layout or anything else ?

Thank You.